# How do I solve ApiPlatform authentication error?

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I have an APIPlatform setup, the docker setup. I created several entities, and followed the docs for JWT authentication. I ran the fixture for my first user, and no error. When I try to login, I get the following error.

```
Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.
```

In my logs I see the following.

```
db_1       | 2020-02-16 20:19:05.700 UTC [11594] ERROR:  column t0.id does not exist at character 8
```

I can see the table with \d+ user and but I can't use it

Comment: So, seems user is reserved keyword, but then how to modify the api-platform to always surround it in quotes

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the right solution, but I changed table name in entity

```
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
```